# Change ViewController if user logged on

Tags: ios, swift

There is such code, if user logged on - ViewController changes :

```
func ifLogged() {
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let token = "token"
    if preferences.object(forKey: token) == nil {
        //  Doesn't exist and stop at the same viewController
    } else {
        let newViewController = GeneralChooser()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: false)
        //  push new generalChooser when logged
    }
}
```

But in this case I do not see view elements, just background color from ViewHelper class

```
class GeneralChooser: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ViewHelper.BackGroundColor(view: self.view)
```

There is BackgroundColor func below

```
class func BackGroundColor(view: UIView){
    let startColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.50, blue:0.70, alpha:1.0)
    let endColor = UIColor(red:0.58, green:0.65, blue:0.81, alpha:1.0)
    let newLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    newLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor,endColor.cgColor]
    newLayer.zPosition = -1
    newLayer.frame = view.frame
    view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
```

If i do not call this function in `GeneralChooser` class, the screen is black and there are not view elements, but in initial ViewController i see view elements, just background color is default.

What am I doing wrong. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
    let newViewController = GeneralChooser()
```

this line doesn't load xib or reference the storyboard object associated with that class

Use **instantiateViewController** and give the viewController storyboard ID in storyboard say **GeneralChooserView**

```
   let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"GeneralChooserView")

   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Or if you are using xibs with GeneralChooser as xib file for GeneralChooser class

```
   let vc = GeneralChooser(nibName: "GeneralChooser", bundle: nil)

   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```